# HiveServer2 - Executes all queries with "hive" user - Bug?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a directory created in hdfs:

```
/user/root/data/gs_landing/cdctest_gs
```

with permissions drwxr-xr-x

I am trying to create an external table with the above location with the following query through java:

```
stmt.execute("create external table cdctest_gs(\n" +
                "    data string\n" +
                "    )\n" +
                "location '/user/root/data/gs_landing/cdctest_gs'");
```

I have created the connection and statement in the following code before the execution of the above query:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000", "root", "");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Now although I am creating the connection as root user, I get the following error after executing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/user/root/data/gs_landing/cdctest_gs":root:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

I am confused as to why HiveServer2 is trying to connect to hive as 'hive' user even though I have explicitly connected using 'root'. Is this a biug with hiveserver2 or is there some property I have missed configuring?

Please feel free to ask for any further inputs. Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding these two properties in hive-site.xml to true:

```
hive.metastore.execute.setugi
hive.server2.enable.doAs
```

More information here:

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR40x/Using+HiveServer2#UsingHiveServer2-EnablingSSLforHiveServer2